# JS - If statement operator, how does this even compile?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading over some javascript and trying to use pieces of it for a similar build I'm doing in Java(android) and there is an if statement that I came across that i just can't seem to understand how it even complies in Javascript.

```
// Decrementing
if (mod < 0) {
    // Check tree rank requirements
    for (var i in state[tree])
        if (i != index)
            // Figure out tier, multiply by 4 to get req points
            if (state[tree][i] > 0 && 
                // Calculate points in this tree up to this tier, and
                // subtract one if we're removing from this portion
                masteryPointReq(tree, i) > treePoints(tree, masteryTier(tree, i)) - (masteryTier(tree, index) < masteryTier(tree, i)))
                return false;
}
```

More Specifically the part I don't understand is the 3rd if statement.

```
if (state[tree][i] > 0 && 
                // Calculate points in this tree up to this tier, and
                // subtract one if we're removing from this portion
                masteryPointReq(tree, i) > treePoints(tree, masteryTier(tree, i)) - (masteryTier(tree, index) < masteryTier(tree, i)))
                return false;
```

What is the "-" operator doing in this and how is it not breaking the if statement? My knowledge of Javascript is limited to just a little tinkering, so not much.

Comment: that means `treePoints(tree, masteryTier(tree, i)) MINUS (masteryTier(tree, index)`

Comment: I'd have to say that is horrible unreadable javascript.  Some intermediates would make this a lot more understandable and maintainable.  I prefer readable and maintainable over brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sums up to an integer

```
var a = 3;
var b = 4;
console.log(5 - (a > b));// a > b == false
// 5
console.log(5 - (b > a));// b > a == true
// 4
```

false = 0, true = 1
hence the comment:

```
// subtract **one** if we're removing from this portion
```

Answer (score 0):

the 3rd if statement is an also possible way how to write conditions in JavaScript.
If the code which should be executed is a single instruction you don't need the braces.
But it's a not so nice style viewed from a point If you plan to get the code passed from [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) or jslint.